# Class mutable.HashTable in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, hashtable

The on-line documentation doesn't say too much about it (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/mutable/HashTable.html), and it's impossible to find any example of its usage. 
I'm wondering how to even put elements into a `mutable.HashTable`.

Are there any data structure with the same constant time complexity in research and delete operations that i could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutable.HashTable` is a trait.

```
trait HashTable[A, Entry >: Null <: HashEntry[A, Entry]] extends HashTable.HashUtils[A]
```

with default load factor as 75%

```
private[collection] final def defaultLoadFactor: Int = 750
```

uses array for implementation,

```
protected var table: Array[HashEntry[A, Entry]] = new Array(initialCapacity)
```

**1) you have to use implementations of `HashTable`, which are `mutable.HashMap` or `mutable.LinkedHashMap`.**

example,

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

scala> new HashMap[String, String]
res9: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String] = Map()
```

**add element**

```
scala> res9+= "order-id-1" -> "delivered"
res10: res9.type = Map(order-id-1 -> delivered)

scala> res9
res11: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String] = Map(order-id-1 -> delivered)
```

**access element**

```
scala> res9("order-id-1")
res12: String = delivered
```

**Write complexity** should be O(1) same as in hashmap datastructure. You find the hashcode and add to the array of Entry.

```
  def += (kv: (A, B)): this.type = {
    val e = findOrAddEntry(kv._1, kv._2)
    if (e ne null) e.value = kv._2
    this
  }

  protected def findOrAddEntry[B](key: A, value: B): Entry = {
    val h = index(elemHashCode(key))
    val e = findEntry0(key, h)
    if (e ne null) e else { addEntry0(createNewEntry(key, value), h); null }
  }

  private[this] def findEntry0(key: A, h: Int): Entry = {
    var e = table(h).asInstanceOf[Entry]
    while (e != null && !elemEquals(e.key, key)) e = e.next
    e
  }

  private[this] def addEntry0(e: Entry, h: Int) {
    e.next = table(h).asInstanceOf[Entry]
    table(h) = e
    tableSize = tableSize + 1
    nnSizeMapAdd(h)
    if (tableSize > threshold)
      resize(2 * table.length)
  }
```

**2. If you use `LinkedHashMap` it maintains the order of insertion with use of linked entries**

```
  @transient protected var firstEntry: Entry = null
  @transient protected var lastEntry: Entry = null
```

example,

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

scala> LinkedHashMap[String, String]()
res0: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String] = Map()

scala> res0 += "line-item1" -> "Delivered" += "line-item2" -> "Processing"
res2: res0.type = Map(line-item1 -> Delivered, line-item2 -> Processing)

scala> res0
res3: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String] = Map(line-item1 -> Delivered, line-item2 -> Processing)
```

Comment: You were really exhaustive. So i can use `LinkedHashMap` too. Thank you! Now i'm wondering how to output a LinkedHashMap instead of a Map in this code:

`def merge[K, V](maps: Seq[scala.collection.Map[K, V]])(f: (K, V, V) => V): scala.collection.Map[K, V] =
      {
      maps.foldLeft(Map.empty[K, V]) { case (merged, m) =>
        m.foldLeft(merged) { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
          acc.get(k) match {
            case Some(existing) => acc.updated(k, f(k, existing, v))
            case None => acc.updated(k, v)
          }
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: @Andrea you probably can not convert map into `LinkedHashMap` if you care about the order of insertion. HashMap does not maintain the order of insertion as you are indexing by hashcode. `LinkedHashMap` does maintain order with linked entries. Use `LinkedinHashMap` in first place. See updated answer.